# как в методе main дождаться завершения всех потоков?

Tags: java, многопоточность

есть цикл:

```
List<Thread>list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0 i < n ; i++){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new MyClass());
    thread.start();
    list.add(thread)
}
```

после этого мне нужно взять у потоков некоторые результаты, нужно чтоб потоки работали все вместе.Как в main дождаться всех потоков?
метод `Thread.currentThread.join();` приводит к тому, что приложение не заканчивается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread.currentThread().join();` - означает что основной тред сам себя будет ждать и поэтому никогда не закончится.

Вам нужно вызывать `thread.join()` по каждому созданному потоку.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (Thread thread : list) {
    thread.join();
}
```